How is this derivative assumed to be -1?
A photo of the partial differential equation book
I get almost every point in this picture, except for one point: it is assumed that f(x,y,u)=aux+buy-c=0.
Then the gradient is derived as (fx,fy,fu) = (fx,fy,-1). How did the book assume/derive fu (partial derivative of f with respect to u) to be -1?

It's not assumed. $d_u(-u)=-1$.

When writing "$u = u(x,y)$" and later when writing "$f(x,y,u)=0$ where $f(x,y,u) \equiv u(x,y) - u$", we are using the symbol $u$ in two ways:

As a variable: one of the three coordinates of $xyu$-space.
As a function which gives us the value of that variable at the point of the solution surface with first two coordinates $x$ and $y$.

It might be more clear to separate these two roles, and say that we assume the existence of a function $g$ (rather than a function $u$) such that the solution surface has the form $u = g(x,y)$, or the form $f(x,y,u)=0$ where $f(x,y,u) \equiv g(x,y)-u$.
Now it is much easier to see that the partial derivative of $f(x,y,u)$ with respect to the variable $u$ is $-1$, because in the expression $g(x,y)-u$, the first term is constant with respect to $u$.
